# Why can't upload files into dropbox at shutdown?

Tags: autorun, systemctl

Fix as jayant  say.

```
cat upload.sh    
/home/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh upload  -f /home/Dropbox-Uploader/.dropbox_uploader   /home/material/*  /
date >>  /home/upload.log
```

All files in directory material can be uploaded into my dropbox with `bash upload.sh`.
I want to write a autorun service at shutdown to upload files into dropbox.

```
vim  /etc/systemd/system/upload.service
[Unit]
Description=upload files into dropbox
Before=network.target shutdown.target  reboot.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash  /home/upload.sh 
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable it with:

```
sudo systemctl enable upload.service
```

To reboot it.

```
journalctl -u upload

-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-01-18 22:38:54 EST, end at Tue 2018-04-10 06:55:43 EDT. --
Apr 10 06:48:27 localhost systemd[1]: Started upload files into dropbox.
Apr 10 06:48:27 localhost systemd[1]: Starting upload files into dropbox...
Apr 10 06:48:27 localhost bash[111]: which: no shasum in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)
Apr 10 06:48:27 localhost bash[111]: > Uploading "/home/material/test.txt" to "/test.txt"...
Apr 10 06:48:27 localhost bash[111]: Error: Couldn't resolve host.
```

`ln -s /usr/bin/sha1sum /usr/bin/shasum` according to [google's result](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/507).

Reboot the second time.

```
journalctl -u dropbox
Apr 10 06:55:04 localhost systemd[1]: Started upload files into dropbox.
Apr 10 06:55:04 localhost systemd[1]: Starting upload files into dropbox...
Apr 10 06:55:04 localhost bash[113]: shasum: invalid option -- 'a'
Apr 10 06:55:04 localhost bash[113]: Try 'shasum --help' for more information.
Apr 10 06:55:04 localhost bash[113]: shasum: invalid option -- 'a'
Apr 10 06:55:04 localhost bash[113]: Try 'shasum --help' for more information.
Apr 10 06:55:04 localhost bash[113]: > Uploading "/home/material/test.txt" to "/test.txt"...
Apr 10 06:55:04 localhost bash[113]: Error: Couldn't resolve host.
```

Do as Raushan say,new issue arised,

```
Uploading    by 4 chunks *** FAILED   dropbox
```

For the problem  `Uploading    by 4 chunks *** FAILED   dropbox` ,some material say that if files exceeding 150 mb should be uploaded in chunks.

```
split -b 10m  /home/upload.tar.gz  /home/material/dropbox
ls  /home/material
dropboxaa  dropboxac  dropboxae  dropboxag  ......
```

Both of them is less than 10m.

```
journalctl -u upload
Apr 19 01:45:26 localhost systemd[1]: Started upload files into dropbox.
Apr 19 01:45:26 localhost systemd[1]: Starting upload files into dropbox...
Apr 19 01:45:27 localhost bash[401]: > Uploading "/home/material/dropboxaa" to "/dropboxaa"... FAILED
Apr 19 01:45:27 localhost bash[401]: An error occurred requesting /upload
Apr 19 01:45:28 localhost bash[401]: > Uploading "/home/material/dropboxab" to "/dropboxab"... FAILED
Apr 19 01:45:40 localhost bash[401]: Some error occured. Please check the log.
Apr 19 01:45:40 localhost systemd[1]: upload.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 19 01:45:40 localhost systemd[1]: Unit upload.service entered failed state.
Apr 19 01:45:40 localhost systemd[1]: upload.service failed.
```

Why `> Uploading "/home/material/dropboxaa" to "/dropboxaa"... FAILED`?

Comment: See if this helps https://superuser.com/questions/1016827/how-do-i-run-a-script-before-everything-else-on-shutdown-with-systemd

Comment: You shouldn't create the symlink from `sha1sum` to `shasum` because `sha1sum` doesn't support the `-a` option that is used in `dropbox_uploader.sh`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible that the second instruction of your script executes without executing the first one. Try redirecting the error output of the `dropbox_uploader.sh` to see what is failing.

Assuming you are using [dropbox-uploader](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader/blob/master/dropbox_uploader.sh), try specifying the exact location of the configuration file. See *Running as cron job* section in their [README.md](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader/blob/master/README.md)

```
/home/Dropbox-Uploader/dropbox_uploader.sh -f /path/to/.dropbox_uploader upload /home/material/*  /
```

Comment: Add `-f /path/to/.dropbox_uploader` in my bash script.

Comment: Two problem remains.

Comment: 1.shasum problem

Comment: Do you mean that you can this script successfully as a normal user and you only see the problems when running as service? In that case please check `which shasum` and ensure that it is available in `PATH` when your service runs. For your second issue try [this](https://serverfault.com/a/708488/462088)

Answer (score 0):

**For the *Couldn't resolve host* problem :**

Unit configuration should have dependency like 
`After=network.target` instead of `Before=network.target` as the default shutdown order is inverse of startup

```
[Unit]
Description=upload files into dropbox
Before=shutdown.target  reboot.target
After=network.target 

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/bash  /home/upload.sh 
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Refer: https://serverfault.com/a/785355

**For the *shasum* problem :**

I am not sure about your OS distro, I am using Fedora 25.

In my case `shasum` binary is from `perl-Digest-SHA` package which can be installed by command `yum install perl-Digest-SHA` on RedHat based linux distro

Refer: https://superuser.com/a/1180163

Comment: shasum  problem remains,please try in your pc.

Comment: New issue arised, Uploading    by 4 chunks *** FAILED   dropbox.